# how to create website using asp.net and sql server 2005 as backend?

Tags: sql-server

How to create website in asp.net and sql server 2005 as backend?
And i wants to know it is possible to use stored procedure in this Website?
How to upload this website into server?

Comment: You need to be much clearer in what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the mainstream support has ended and extended support is scheduled to end in about 3 years 12-04-2016

Not the best idea to use it. Look at SQL Server 2012 instead.

That said, technically you can use SQL 2005. But then, you can also write each record as a `.txt` to the file system. Just because you can does not mean you should

http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=SQL

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about using sql as the backend to the site, then yes, it is possible. ASP.NET sites will typically use MSSQL for the backend if a backend is required. This is not a hard and fast rule, however.

Comment: my doubt is we should host the website in server means how to host sql server in website domain server?